# How to ask a question which is already asked on mathstackexchange?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

There was [A Question in vector Calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1637668/calculate-the-vector-surface-integral/2578719#2578719), that can be solved by two methods that I know. Problem was both methods were giving different answers. I searched it and found it to be already asked with one of my methods showing his approach. So I posted the answer with another method hoping that we will conclude the right result together by discussion, but no reply came.

I am still stuck with the question, which method is right and why?
I can't ask it on stackexchange. Please suggest me what I can do  to get the answer.

Comment: I see no problem with you asking a follow up question about any possible issues you see with the answer.

Comment: Of course including a link to the previously asked Question will help provide context for the follow-up Question as @Qudit suggests.

Comment: Thanks it will be helpful for the future.I was lucky this time because Daniel Fischer answered all my questions after reading this post